# Landau gauge momentum conservation question

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields, commutator

I'm having an issue understanding why $\hat{P}_x$ commutes with the Hamiltonian in the Landau gauge ($A_x=-B\hat{Y}, A_y=0$) in two dimensions. I've been finding elsewhere online the hand-wavey argument that this is because the Hamiltonian is independent of $\hat{X}$. I want to be able to show this more rigorously, i.e. by applying the commutator to a test function, but I don't know what kind of assumptions to make about such test functions (obviously they would be wavefunctions considering the Hamiltonian's application in the Schrodinger equation). I would appreciate it if anyone could offer a hint.

Comment: It may help if you think of $\hat{P}_x$ as a partial derivative (with the proper factors of $i$ and $\hbar$). Then you can check explicitly that the operator commutes with the Hamiltonian. As for your test function, it can be an arbitrary wavefunction, dependent on both $x$ and $y$.